# MYSQL Select rows where date is older than datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, where-clause

I am coding a status item for a website and need to load statuses older than a variable that contains a datetime.

So the database has a field called added date which is a datetime field and I have a string in datetime format and i want to select all rows older than my datetime format string.

How would this be structured in MYSQL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everyone, PLEASE NOTE: the format is DATETIME....

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
 select status_column from your_table
 where added_date < '2012-05-12'
```

Comment: Hi there, it's actually datetime format will it still work? i.e. 2012-05-12 14:23:23

Comment: the OP says 'older than', shouldn't the `>` be a `<`?

Comment: `>` for newer, **`<`** for older... :)

Comment: @AndréFigueira: Yes it will work with `datetime` strings as well.

Comment: @juergend Hi I just tested, it doesn't work with datetime.... only partially but misses out a lot of dates.

Comment: @AndréFigueira: Works for me. See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fa3e/1)

Comment: @juergend using your method with the following query: SELECT * from status WHERE addedDate < '2012-01-01 00:00:00' Returns just one results, when it should be returning 4

Comment: @AndréFigueira: That is odd. The SQLFiddle example works. Even after you added other years. Try `where date(added_date) < cast('2012-05-12 10:00:00' as date)`

Answer (score 5):

mysql DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts.

Try this

```
SELECT datecolumn 
FROM table
WHERE datetime_date > '2012-05-12 01-32-56'
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');

 SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE year(added_date) > $today AND month(added_date) > $today
```